# Understanding Time Zone in PostgreSQL >= 9.3

Tags: postgresql, timezone, timestamp

I am struggling in understanding how PostgreSQL is working with `TIMESTAMP` and `TIME ZONE`. I have a Debian Server where *timezone* is set to UTC running PostgreSQL 9.3 where cluster's `postgresql.conf` file is also set to UTC. My client is `PgAdmin` and my computer locale is also set to UTC. Therefore, all timezones are equals, there are no offsets and no DST in storage or display.

I have read many posts over the internet and I cannot understand the following output of my queries.

I assume as true the following affirmations:

- Default data-type `TIMESTAMP` is `WITHOUT TIME ZONE`;
- PostgreSQL stores all `TIMESTAMP` and `TIMESTAMPTZ` in UTC;
- When using `TIMESTAMP` type, timezone conversion **is not** performed;
- When using `TIMESTAMPTZ` type timezone conversion **is** performed;
- POSIX and ISO standards define offset in a opposite fashion;
- PostgreSQL display in ISO format but abbreviation are POSIX compliant.

**First question:** are all those statements right?

Then I checked it out, issuing:

```
SELECT '2000-01-01 00:00:00' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC-1';
-- Result: 2000-01-01 01:00:00
--         UTC --> LT
--         TIMESTAMP 
SELECT '2000-01-01 00:00:00'::TIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'UTC-1';
-- Result: 1999-12-31 23:00:00+00
--         LT --> UTC
--         TIMESTAMPTZ
SELECT '2000-01-01 00:00:00'::TIMESTAMPTZ AT TIME ZONE 'UTC-1';
-- Result: 2000-01-01 01:00:00
--         UTC --> LT
--         TIMESTAMP
```

This is very confusing to me because:

- it looks like default data-type infered from string without cast is `TIMESTAMPTZ` instead of `TIMESTAMP`;
- conversion is performed in different way when using different data-type;
- when specifying data-type with casting `::operator` it is the opposite type that is retured.

**Second question:** How must I interpret the result of those three queries?

**Bonus question:** I have read [there](http://justatheory.com/computers/databases/postgresql/use-timestamptz.html) that it is better to always store data with `TIMESTAMPTZ`. Is this a good practice?

Thank you further for your help!